# Customizing generated ASP.NET MVC form element names using data annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Typically I'm ok with the auto-generated form element names when using the HTML helper like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Property)
```

Unfortunately, I have a requirement to create an `input` with a specific `name` attribute.

I realize I can just build the input using normal HTML and use a model binder or a `BindAttribute` to retrieve its submitted value.  However, I wanted to see if there was a way for me to *attribute a property* instead to specify both the generated input name and enable the binding.

Is this possible?  If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Description

One way to set the name of the `input` element is to use a overload of `TextBoxFor`.
But this would result in problems with the default model binder. You can create your own ModelBinder to solve this issue.

#### Sample

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Property, new { @name = "YourName" })
```

Comment: Yeah, as I've said, I know I can do it that way but was hoping for something simpler.  I've went with this for now.  Will wait a bit longer for different approaches before accepting.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest simply having a hidden input with the bound name, then rendering a separate input with the expected name.  Assuming this is for a JS control.  From there, bind the change event for the visible input to clone to the hidden input.